# FFmpeg HLS Segmenting start time miscalculated

Tags: video, ffmpeg, h.264, rtsp, http-live-streaming

Trying to re-stream and record my Hikvision IP camera with `ffmpeg` via HLS.

So basically everything works fine, however, when I am trying to calculate the duration of an entire day of record, it results in mismatches between segmented TS files.

So basically what I am doing in FFmpeg:

```
"ffmpeg",
"-rtsp_transport", "tcp",
"-stimeout", "3000000",
"-re",
"-i", stream,
"-vcodec", "copy",
"-acodec", "libfdk_aac",
"-f", "segment",
"-segment_list_type", "m3u8",
"-segment_list", name,
"-segment_list_size", "1",
"-segment_format", "mpegts",
"-segment_time", "5",
segment_filename,
```

And the result is:

```
filename   cam1-1502731225-000018.ts
start_time 90.128000
end_time   96.150489

filename    cam1-1502731225-000019.ts
start_time  96.128000
end_time    102.150489

filename    cam1-1502731225-000020.ts
start_time  102.128000
end_time    105.150489
```

So each end_time of a file should be the same as the start_time of the next file. Though it does not so.

Have lost days to find a solution - so far no luck! But I did observe, that if I output the video to MP4 file and then proceed that as an input (for the same command line) - it will be ok.

I am assuming it has to be an issue with PTS of an original RTSP URL. When tried to apply `-filter_complex setpts=N/(16*TB)` - it fixed the issue but draws CPU resources for encoding.

Answer (score 0):

Audio frames and video are not the exact same length. The start and end times are probably calculated based on whatever stream starts first, and ends last. So if audio ends 20ms before video in one segment, Its must start 20ms early in the next.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I have thought exact the same thing, tried different options (for example -an (no audio) - same thing. Can you advice me something?

Comment: My advice to is ignore it.